# Native SVG looping animation

Tags: css, animation, svg

I created a very simple SVG animation with two circles, a solid one inside a dashed one. It was simple to animate a 360-degree rotation of the outer dashed circle.

What I'd like to try is to have the inner, solid circle "pulse" by scaling down maybe 10% then back up to 100%.

The problem is, so far all the docs I've found for `animateTransform` involve 2 "keyframes" only, from-to.  Therefore, the circle would go from 100% to 90% and then it will repeat and jump back to 100%.  I'm looking for it to "ping-pong", to go `100->90->100->90` etc.

Can this be done with native SVG animation (i.e. no CSS and no libraries)?

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="106" height="106" viewBox="0 0 106 106" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <circle id="a" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    <mask id="b" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="white">
      <use xlink:href="#a"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(3 3)">
    <use stroke="#979797" stroke-width="12" mask="url(#b)" stroke-dasharray="6 9" xlink:href="#a">
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                       attributeType="XML"
                       type="rotate"
                       from="0 50 50"
                       to="360 50 50"
                       dur="10s"
                       repeatCount="indefinite"  />
    </use>
    <circle cx="50.5" cy="50.5" r="36.5" fill="#D8D8D8"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer hidden away, if anyone is interested.  For the inner circle:

```
  <circle cx="50.5" cy="50.5" r="36" fill="#084b86">
      <animate attributeName="r"
               values="36;20;36"
               dur="2s"
               repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
```

The key is the `values` attribute, which can take a semi-colon-separated list.

If anyone knows a better or smarter way, please share!